# First attempt at using new to dynamically create struct array, program hangs without error

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, struct, new-operator

I'm trying to work out how to create a dynamic array for an assignment, but no matter what I seem to do my program continues to hang after I enter 3 or more entries.

I'm not getting any errors, and have to manually close the console window, but without any sort of direction I'm unsure of what exactly I've done wrong.

No matter what I change if I create 3+ structs in the console my program hangs after entering 'n' to end the creation of new Events.

```
int readEvents(Event* ev_ptr[], int size)
{
    char answer = 'y', slash;
    int i = 0;

    cout << "\nCreate an event [y/n]? ";
    cin >> answer;
    cin.ignore();
    while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        ev_ptr[i] = new Event;

        cout << "\nEnter description: ";
        cin.getline(ev_ptr[i]->desc, 80, '\n');

        cout << "\nEnter date: ";
        cin >> ev_ptr[i]->date.month >> slash >> ev_ptr[i]->date.day >> slash >> ev_ptr[i]->date.year;
        cin.ignore();

        cout << "\nEnter time: ";
        cin >> ev_ptr[i]->time.hour >> slash >> ev_ptr[i]->time.minute;
        cin.ignore();

        i++;

        cout << "\nCreate an event [y/n]? ";
        cin >> answer;
        cin.ignore();
    }

    return i;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Edit:

Here's my main function where the ev_ptr array size is declared:

```
int main()
{
    Event* event_pointers[100];
    int count = readEvents(event_pointers, 100), userMonth;
    char userString[80];

    cout << "\nEnter a search string: ";
    cin.getline(userString, 80, '\n');
    cin.ignore();

    linsearch(event_pointers, count, userString);

    cout << "\nEnter a month to list Events for: ";
    cin >> userMonth;
    cin.ignore();

    binsearch(event_pointers, count, userMonth);

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) //Cleanup loop
        delete event_pointers[j];

    cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";
    (void)_getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the size of an array that you pass as ev_ptr parameter?

Comment: Please, show us the code that calls `readEvents`. OT: Why do you pass the array size if you don't check for it when assigning elements?

Comment: In modern C++ its almost never a good idea to use `new` directly. Use `std::vector` instead of array which directly contains `Event` instead of pointer. If you for some reason really need to have pointers, then use either `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @sklott Assignments quite frequently require one to use `new` directly.

Comment: Then I'm not sure if there exist good solutions for this assignment except in "reinventing" `std::vector'...

Comment: It's hard to tell where the problem is by looking at just one function. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Think about what will happen when the user wants to add more events than the size of the `ev_ptr` array.  And as Konstantin asked, what _is_ the size of the `ev_ptr` array? Show the declaration of it.

Comment: Sorry guys, edited main post to show my main function!

Comment: Have you tried to use debugger or just debug-print the input values? It looks like you're dealing with some tricky input format, and once `cin` tries to read something and fails it starts to ignore following inputs, which may lead to infinite loop unless handled.

Comment: @sklott the assignment unfortunately requires me to use new

Comment: `Event* event_pointers[100];` does not look like a dynamic array.

Comment: @DenisSheremet I've not, I'd assumed because the hang only occurs when 3 or more entries are made (And it doesn't hang until I input 'n' to stop collecting inputs) that it was likely something more than just input error

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, did I misinterpret the way that functioned? I was led to believe from some examples that this was the proper way to initialize the array of pointers that would then be used to direct to the dynamic array created in my readEvents function, was I mistaken?

Comment: What you've done is the proper way to declare an array of exactly 100 pointers. There's nothing dynamic about it. `Event* event_pointers = new Event[size];` would make it dynamic, but without the ability to grow dynamically.

Comment: @TedLyngmo would this cause the program to hang though? In all of my examples the book seems to establish statically sized pointer arrays but then makes an array of a dynamic size like how I did.

Comment: No, that will not cause it to hang. I'm just saying it's not dynamic. If the user wants to enter 200 events you need to change your program and  recompile. That's not dynamic.

Comment: `while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')` ==> `while (i < size && (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y'))`

Comment: If you have to use `new`, don't declare an array of pointers first, simply use a single pointer to `Event` and allocate for `100` struct `Event`. Then if you hit your `100` limit, allocate for `200` in a temporary pointer and copy the exiting data, `delete[]` your exiting `100` and assign the temp pointer to the original and keep going. This provides the benefit of a single `new` and `delete[]` per-block of struct `Event` allocated, not having to `new` and `delete` every struct individually. You don't need `cin.ignore();` after `cin.getline (... '\n')` it extracts the `'\n'`.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the suggestions, changing the while loop didn't seem to solve the hanging issue any.

As for your second suggestion, I'm not quite sure I understand, I should create a single pointer instead of an array of pointers, and then create an array of Event structs with size 100?

I believe I've narrowed down the problem to be related to the pointers as lowering the size from 100 to 10 makes it so I can enter 4 instead of 3 before the program hangs

Comment: Changing the while loop was simply to *Protect The Bound* of your array. It prevents you from adding `101` elements where you array can only hold `100`. For the second, right now you declare `Event* event_pointers[100];` (100 pointers to `Event`) then you have to allocate for every `Event`. Instead simply do `Event *event = new Event[100];` (which will allocated for instances of `Event` in one-shot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `new` and `delete` is somewhat the old way of doing things. Being the old way of doing things, there are decades worth of code making use of it. As summarized in my comments above, you currently declare `100` *pointers-to-type* `Event`, and then use `new` to allocate storage for each individual `struct Event` instance. By using a fixed array of pointers -- you are locked in to having no more events that you initially declare pointers for. That is a very inflexible way to go.

Instead, simply declare a block of memory to hold some initial number of events, and keep a pair of counters for the number of elements allocated and number of elements filled. When `filled == allocated`, simply allocate another block of memory (say holding twice as many elements as the current), and copy the data from the original block to the new block, delete the original, and repeat as many times as required. (you are basically performing a manual `realloc()` using `new/delete`.

A short example follows. In the example I use a simplified `Event` struct. (you can handle further splitting the dates and time into *yyyy-mm-dd* and *H:M:S*). The example starts by initially allocating 2 instances of `Event` and then continues reading as much input as the user has, updating the allocation size and copying original to new as required. The initial setup and reallocation code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define MAXDESC  80    /* max description length */
#define MAXDTTM  32    /* max date/time lengths */
#define EVSIZE    2    /* initial number of Event elements allocated */

struct Event {
    char desc[MAXDESC];
    char date[MAXDTTM];
    char time[MAXDTTM];
};

/** reallocate e to twice 'size' elements */
Event *reallocEVx2 (Event *e, size_t *size)
{
    Event *tmp = new Event[*size * 2];      /* allocate new block 2x in size */

    std::memcpy (tmp, e, *size * sizeof *e);    /* copy old to new */
    delete[] e;                                 /* delete old */
    *size *= 2;                                 /* update allocated size */

    return tmp;     /* return pointer to new block */
}
```

The `readEvents()` function takes the **address-of** your original pointer as a parameter, since the beginning address will change on reallocation. So instead of just passing a pointer, you pass the *address-of* the pointer from the caller so you can update that address to point to your newly reallocated block of memory in `readEvents()`. That change will be seen back in the caller because you are operating on the original pointer address. If you didn't pass the *address-of* the original pointer, you would have to return a pointer to the newly allocated block and assign that to your pointer back in the caller.

The implementation for `readEvents()` does away with mixing `getline` and `>>` on `std::cin`. Instead simply use `getline` and create a `stringstream` from each line to further separate the data into individual values using `>>` on the stringstream. This eliminates the potential for an invalid input failing to be read and remaining unread in your input stream just waiting to bite you on your next input.

A slight rewrite of your `readEvents()` simply loops taking input until the user types something other than `'y'` when prompted:

```
/** read events from user reallocating as required
 *  (note: must pass address-of-pointer, not just pointer)
 */
size_t readEvents (Event **e, size_t *nelem, size_t *size)
{
    char buf[MAXDESC];

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until something other than 'y' entered */
        std::cout << "\nCreate event (y/n)? ";
        if (!std::cin.getline (buf, sizeof buf) || *buf != 'y')
            break;

        if (*nelem == *size)    /* check if realloc needed */
            *e = reallocEVx2 (*e, size);

        /* get input */
        std::cout << "  Enter description: ";
        if (!std::cin.getline ((*e)[*nelem].desc, MAXDESC))
            break;

        std::cout << "  Enter date: ";
        if (!std::cin.getline ((*e)[*nelem].date, MAXDTTM))
            break;
        /* create stringstream to parse date into yyyy-mm-dd here */

        std::cout << "  Enter time: ";
        if (!std::cin.getline ((*e)[*nelem].time, MAXDTTM))
            break;
        /* create stringstream to parse time into H:M:S here */

        (*nelem)++;     /* update no. of elements filled */
    }
    return *nelem;      /* return no. of elements filled */
}
```

In `main()`, you simply declare your counters to track the allocated number of elements (`size` below) and the number of elements used (`nelem` below) and allocate for your initial two instances of `Event` and starts reading data. The code finishes by outputting the memory statistics (allocated elements/used elements) and outputs each stored `Event` instance, e.g.

```
int main (void) {

    size_t nelem = 0;
    size_t size = EVSIZE;
    Event *events = new Event[size];    /* allocate initial 'size' elements */

    if (!readEvents (&events, &nelem, &size)) {     /* read/fill events */
        std::cerr << "error: no events read.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    /* output memory useage (elements allocated/filled) */
    std::cout << "\nelements allocated: " << size <<
                 "\nelements filled   : " << nelem << "\n\n"; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nelem; i++)  /* output all events */
        std::cout << events[i].desc << "    " << events[i].date << "    " <<
                    events[i].time << '\n';

    delete[] events;    /* free memory  */
}
```

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define MAXDESC  80    /* max description length */
#define MAXDTTM  32    /* max date/time lengths */
#define EVSIZE    2    /* initial number of Event elements allocated */

struct Event {
    char desc[MAXDESC];
    char date[MAXDTTM];
    char time[MAXDTTM];
};

/** reallocate e to twice 'size' elements */
Event *reallocEVx2 (Event *e, size_t *size)
{
    Event *tmp = new Event[*size * 2];      /* allocate new block 2x in size */

    std::memcpy (tmp, e, *size * sizeof *e);    /* copy old to new */
    delete[] e;                                 /* delete old */
    *size *= 2;                                 /* update allocated size */

    return tmp;     /* return pointer to new block */
}

/** read events from user reallocating as required
 *  (note: must pass address-of-pointer, not just pointer)
 */
size_t readEvents (Event **e, size_t *nelem, size_t *size)
{
    char buf[MAXDESC];

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until something other than 'y' entered */
        std::cout << "\nCreate event (y/n)? ";
        if (!std::cin.getline (buf, sizeof buf) || *buf != 'y')
            break;

        if (*nelem == *size)    /* check if realloc needed */
            *e = reallocEVx2 (*e, size);

        /* get input */
        std::cout << "  Enter description: ";
        if (!std::cin.getline ((*e)[*nelem].desc, MAXDESC))
            break;

        std::cout << "  Enter date: ";
        if (!std::cin.getline ((*e)[*nelem].date, MAXDTTM))
            break;
        /* create stringstream to parse date into yyyy-mm-dd here */

        std::cout << "  Enter time: ";
        if (!std::cin.getline ((*e)[*nelem].time, MAXDTTM))
            break;
        /* create stringstream to parse time into H:M:S here */

        (*nelem)++;     /* update no. of elements filled */
    }

    return *nelem;      /* return no. of elements filled */
}

int main (void) {

    size_t nelem = 0;
    size_t size = EVSIZE;
    Event *events = new Event[size];    /* allocate initial 'size' elements */

    if (!readEvents (&events, &nelem, &size)) {     /* read/fill events */
        std::cerr << "error: no events read.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    /* output memory useage (elements allocated/filled) */
    std::cout << "\nelements allocated: " << size <<
                 "\nelements filled   : " << nelem << "\n\n"; 

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nelem; i++)  /* output all events */
        std::cout << events[i].desc << "    " << events[i].date << "    " <<
                    events[i].time << '\n';

    delete[] events;    /* free memory  */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/events_new-del

Create event (y/n)? y
  Enter description: Event 1
  Enter date: 11/29/19
  Enter time: 12:30:31

Create event (y/n)? y
  Enter description: Event 2
  Enter date: 11/29/19
  Enter time: 12:30:41

Create event (y/n)? y
  Enter description: Event 3
  Enter date: 11/29/19
  Enter time: 12:30:51

Create event (y/n)? y
  Enter description: Event 4
  Enter date: 11/29/19
  Enter time: 12:31:01

Create event (y/n)? y
  Enter description: Event 5
  Enter date: 11/29/19
  Enter time: 12:31:11

Create event (y/n)? n

elements allocated: 8
elements filled   : 5

Event 1    11/29/19    12:30:31
Event 2    11/29/19    12:30:41
Event 3    11/29/19    12:30:51
Event 4    11/29/19    12:31:01
Event 5    11/29/19    12:31:11
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions about this approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time, this really helped me understand things better!

Comment: Glad it helped. Like anything, seeing all the pieces put together once really helps them fall into place. Good luck with your coding! You can make the realloc function generic by using templates -- but save that for another day. Just know you can write a generic reallocation function so you don't have to write one for every different type.

Comment: As I commented above, basically this is "reinvention" of `std::vector`, so its best to use it directly whenever you are not required to implement everything yourself. (Its beyond my comprehension why such assignments exist in our time on this level of education, I mean shouldn't you learn how to use `std::vector` before trying to implement it?)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `std::vector` and `std::unique`?

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Event { }

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Event>> events;
  readEvents(events);
}

int readEvents(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Event>>& events, int size)
{
  ...
  while (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
  {
    ev_ptr[i] = std::make_unique<Event>();
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, so it should be a comment, not answer.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not permitted to use vectors for this assignment