# is it possible to change the size of a dynamically created array using new operator

Tags: c++, dynamic

Can we change the size of an array which is created by the `new` operator, like the resizing done using `reallocate()` as shown below?

In C:

```c
int *p = (int*)malloc(size_of(int));
reallocate(p,2*size_of(int));
```

If it is not possible, how to change the size of an array created by the `new` operator?

Comment: No, it's not possible. In C++, `std::vector` should be used for such purpose. It manages the re-allocation under the hood.

Comment: Sometimes the reinvention of `std::vector` is the entire point of the learning exercise. While STL is nice and should be used going forward, there are more than 2 decades of legacy code out there using various `new` and `delete` reallocation schemes. See similar questions [First attempt at using new to dynamically create struct array, program hangs without error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59110143/3422102)

Comment: The C function to reallocate is named `realloc`, not `reallocate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`new`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) with [**`std::copy`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)/[**`std::move`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) here.

```
#include<iostream>
//              --> reference to a pointer
//              |
void resize(int*& begin, const int curr_size, const int size){
    int* temp = new int[size];
    int resize_val = std::min(curr_size, size);
    std::move(begin, begin+resize_val, temp);
    delete[] begin;
    begin = temp;
}

int main(){
   int* arr = new int[10];
   for(size_t i=0; i<10; ++i)arr[i]=15;
   resize(arr, 10, 20);
   for(size_t i=0; i<20; ++i)std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
   resize(arr, 20 , 5);
   for(size_t i=0; i<5; ++i)std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
   delete[] arr; // delete arr after use
}
```

Output:

```
15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
15 15 15 15 15
```

[**Demo in `cpp.sh`**](http://cpp.sh/5eqcp)

Comment: Your resize, more specifically your copy, doesn't take into account when the requested size is smaller than the current size. In that case, you copy too many elements into the new array.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, agreed. Apart from resizing into a smaller size, does replacing `copy` with `move` improve performance?

Comment: `curr_size<size?curr_size:size` can be replaced with `std::min(curr_size, size)`. And there is no need to set `temp` to `nullptr` since it is going out of scope immediately after. As for performance, a move will always be more, or at least equally, efficient than a copy, depending on the type being moved.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Scheff said, under the hood of `std::vector` new memory gets allocated like below sample code:

```
int *c = new int[10]; // initial

delete[] c;
c = new int[20]; // after resizing

delete[] c; // gets called after after vector goes out of acope
```

Comment: You forgot an important step - you need to copy/move the contents of the old array to the new array, after allocating the new array and before destroying the old array.